# How to add the information in NSMutableDictionary from two plist?

Tags: ios, plist, addition, nsmutabledictionary

I have two plist. How to add the information in NSMutableDictionary from two plist? how to do it from a plist, I know. But I have 2 plist.

```
 NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:
                          @"Eur" ofType:@"plist"];
        NSString *path1 = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:
                          @"Asia" ofType:@"plist"];
        stationDictionary = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:path];
```

I need add in stationDictionary two plist: 1 Eur 2 Asia. But I do not know how to add the information from the second plist?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:
                  @"Eur" ofType:@"plist"];
NSString *path1 = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:
                   @"Asia" ofType:@"plist"];
NSMutableDictionary* stationDictionary = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:path];
NSDictionary* dicForPath1 = [[NSDictionary alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:path1];
[stationDictionary addEntriesFromDictionary:dicForPath1];
```

Comment: MANIAK_dobrii, Thank you:)